# Hide individual page title using checkbox in custom meta box?

Tags: post-meta, metabox, page-template, title

I tried to write code to have a checkbox on Pages in the backend to check if I want to hide the title of the page in frontend. But I find that the post meta is sometimes reset to show the title even if I did set it to "hide the title". This only happens randomly when I edited a page or made some other changes. Please advise on what could be wrong or if there is a better way of doing it?

**Here is my code in functions.php**

```
function mysite_page_metabox() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'remove-title', 
        __('Hide Page Title', 'textdomain' ), 
        'hide_title_callback', 
        'page', 
        'side', 
        'high' 
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes' , 'mysite_page_metabox');

function hide_title_callback() {
    $value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_mysite_meta_hide_title', true);
    ?>
    <?php if($value == "on") : ?>
        <label for="hide">Hide: </label><input type="checkbox" name="hide" checked>
    <?php else : ?>
        <label for="hide">Hide: </label><input type="checkbox" name="hide">
    <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php
}


// Save meta key and value
function mysite_save_postdata($post_id)
{
    if ( isset( $_POST['hide']) ) {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_mysite_meta_hide_title',
            sanitize_text_field( $_POST['hide'] )
        );
    } else {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_mysite_meta_hide_title',
            sanitize_text_field( "off" )
        );
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'mysite_save_postdata');
```

**In my content-page.php template-parts I call it like this:**

```
<!--Start the hide title-->
    <?php 
        $hide_title_status = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_mysite_meta_hide_title', true);
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        if($hide_title_status == "off" || !metadata_exists( 'post', $post_id, '_mysite_meta_hide_title' ) ) :
    ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
    <?php endif; ?> <!--End the hide title-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$value` is always empty because post ID is missing. Pass the parameter (`$post` object) to the `hide_title_callback()` function and get the post ID right way.

Also, you should take care of nonces.

```
<?php
// pass the $post object
function hide_title_callback( $post ) {

    // you have to verify this nonce inside `mysite_save_postdata()`
    // https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field
    wp_nonce_field( 'mysite_action_name', 'mysite_nonce_field_name' );

    // now you have the post ID
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_mysite_meta_hide_title', true );

    if( $value == "on" ) : ?>
        <label for="hide">Hide: </label><input type="checkbox" name="hide" checked>
    <?php else : ?>
        <label for="hide">Hide: </label><input type="checkbox" name="hide">
    <?php endif;
}
```

Verify the nonce

```
<?php
function mysite_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    // https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mysite_nonce_field_name'], 'mysite_action_name' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['hide']) ) {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_mysite_meta_hide_title',
            sanitize_text_field( $_POST['hide'] )
        );
    } else {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            '_mysite_meta_hide_title',
            sanitize_text_field( "off" )
        );
    }
}
```

To keep the database a bit cleaner I personally should not save the 'off' meta value. I should remove the `_mysite_meta_hide_title` completely if checkbox is unchecked. So, it will exist if 'on' and do not if 'off'. `if()` statement in the `hide_title_callback()` will remain intact.

```
<?php
if ( ! isset( $_POST['hide'] ) ) {
    // unchecked
    delete_post_meta(
        $post_id,
        '_mysite_meta_hide_title',
    );
} else {
    // checked
    update_post_meta(
        $post_id,
        '_mysite_meta_hide_title',
        'on' // nothing to sanitize here
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you for the thorough answer. I will definitely consider your option to keep the database cleaner.